# Is there any limit to the number of *undelivered* messages in firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any daily limit on the number of (FCM) messages which are not delivered yet to devices.

[I referred this doc of firebase but not mention what is limit to store undelivered messages in queue.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: @AL. i'm not asking about Firebase FCM Usage Limits.

Comment: You're asking about the number of unsent stored in the FCM server right? Regardless, there is no limit. only with the lifespan (as mentioned in the post I referred to).

Comment: exactly @AL. thanks.!!

Comment: No worries. Cheers! :)

Comment: this question is different than  Firebase FCM Usage Limits @AL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit to the volume/number of unsent messages in the FCM server. There is however, a [lifetime for a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime).